# Jquery override link, work with url

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I have 3 links on a page. All have css class="suggested_product" and an id that is an integer I need to include in the url. I want to override what happens when you click. I have an ajax function that will send some data I am logging to a url, then once that's done redirect the page to the original url. Non-javascript fallback should always go to the original href.

My problem is I haven't found how to get the original url or a#id from inside the click function. The link has an image and a span insde it, and the click event seems to be triggering on those instead of the a tag. I think.

Code that doesn't work:

```
$(function(){
   $("a.suggested_product").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        original_url = e.target.href;
        log_url = "http://domain.com/ajax-controller/"+e.target.id;
        ajaxLogSuggestClick(log_url, original_url)
        return;
   });
});
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, just edited for clarity. I can't get the  href and id from inside the click function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   $(".suggested_product").click(function(){

        //notice the use of the `var` keyword to keep variables local
        var original_url = this.href,
            log_url      = "http://domain.com/ajax-controller/" + this.id;

        //do the AJAX request to your server-side script
        $.ajax({
            url     : log_url,
            type    : 'get',
            success : function (serverResponse) {
                //successfull callback, forward user to original_url
                window.location = original_url;
            },
            error   : function () {
                //an error occured, you probably just want to forward the user to their destination
                window.location = original_url;
            }
        });

        //returning false inside a jQuery Event Handler is the same as calling `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`
        return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Ooooh, this looks way better than what I was doing.

Comment: @SyntaxError Let me know if I can help explain any part of this code.

Comment: I mostly understand what everything is doing. There are a couple typos though (orininal). My only problem is it's not performing the request on localhost or redirecting or anything. I can alert the url vars after I make them and I'm not getting any errors. Using Chrome BTW

Comment: Oh, I think the problem was "window.locaion"

Answer (score 2):

In short, you need to replace

`e.target.href;`

with

`$(this).attr("href");`

AND

`e.target.id;`

with

`$(this).attr("id");`

Comment: In even-shorter: `this.href` and `this.id`. But why do you think `e.target.href` and `e.target.id` won't work? They should...

Comment: Why is that necessary? Using the jQuery methods is slower. The `id` will be the exact same either way and the `href` will still work but you'll get the entire URL using `.href` and you'll get the attribute value when using `.attr('href')` (in this case the user will be redirected to the same place regardless).

Comment: the e var is a handle to the event object.. or something. that's why if you want to prevent the default behaviour on a click event function, you'd say e.preventDefault()...

Comment: This was the answer - short and sweet. Thank you. I'll accept as soon as the site will let me.

Comment: @Ettiene Place this in a jQuery event handler sometime: `console.log(e)`. You'll see that it has a sub-object `e.target` which is the DOM element on which the event fired.

Comment: Sorry pressed return too quick.. Inside the click function, $(this) references the object that the click function is currently bound to, i.e. the specific a element being clicked

Comment: Create an "enormous" object and invoke a method with many actions under the hood just to access a simple attribute of a dom node? and that two times for the same node. Erm, no... ;)

Comment: Thanks Jasper.. Like you, I am just trying to help.

Comment: I believe that the event object is created whether you use it or not.

Comment: FWIW it seems this.href and this.id also work as nnnnnn said.

Comment: @Ettiene Here is a simple test in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xt6gJ/. Watch your log to see the contents of the `event` object (as well as the `event.target` object).

Comment: I'll have to retract the second half of my comment now that I've noticed the question says the anchor has child elements (was that in the question originally?). But definitely `this.href` is better than `$(this).attr("href")`, and creating a jQuery object with `$(this)` twice in a row is inefficient (not a problem for this click handler, but not a good habit to get into).

Comment: I had to give Jasper the accept - his code was exactly what I needed. Thanks your your help as well though.

Answer (score 1):

> The link has an image and a span insde it, and the click event seems to be triggering on those instead of the a tag.

Yes, the click on the children will bubble up to the anchor and thus `e.target` will reference the child element. But jQuery will set `this` to the element you bound the event on, so:

```
$(function(){
   $("a.suggested_product").click(function(e){    
      e.preventDefault();
      ajaxLogSuggestClick(this.href, "http://domain.com/ajax-controller/"+this.id)
   });
});
```

Also, don't create global variables (unless you need them): your `original_url` and `log_url` weren't declared with `var` and so were global. But they were also unnecessary so I've eliminated them in my version of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about globals. I should know better, but for some reason dealing with javascript makes me forget everything I know about anything ;)